# Python: passing Pool objects to a function in different process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

What am I doing wrong in the following code?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process
import numpy as np

def fun(X):
    return X;

def funct(p,i):
    print 'Hey'
    res = [p.map(fun,range(2))];
    return res;


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(2);
    output = mp.Queue();
    proc = [mp.Process(target = funct,args=(pool,i)) for i in range(2)]
    for p in proc:
        p.start()
    for p in proc:
        p.join()
    results = [output.get() for p in proc]
    print results
```

The program doesn't run after launching the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Pool` doesn't support being passed to child processes, as noted in the [`multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers):

> Note that the methods of a pool should only ever be used by the process which created it.

So there actually is no way to do what you're trying. I'm assuming your code above is just an example to demonstrate the problem, so I won't comment on that directly, but you'll need to refactor your actual code to only call pool methods from the parent process (or possibly create the pool in the child itself, but that's probably not a good solution).

Comment: However, "AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children". You cannot create a Pool in pooled function, probably to prevent exponential CPU load growth. So I wanted to make a global pool object and draw from that pool in at all times. Doesn't seem to work either. Great...